# What is the difference between TypeVar and NewType?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

[`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) and [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) seem related but I'm not sure when I'm supposed to use each or what the difference is at runtime and statically.

Comment: I guess `TypeVar` creates a generic type and `NewType` creates a concrete type

Comment: Neither should have a runtime effect, unless some third-party library uses these annotations in some way.

Comment: @dcg `TypeVar` creates a *type variable*, which is different from a generic type. `NewType` is a helper function to create new types, although that is only for any static-time type checkers you may use. No actual python type is created.

Comment: There's no real similarity or relationship between the two. You use TypeVars as a part of the process of creating your own custom [generic functions or classes](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html). You use NewType if you want to create a [subtype of a type](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#newtypes) without going through the trouble of actually writing out a subclass and having it inherit the parent type.

Comment: Here's a good description of the use-case for NewType: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#newtype-helper-function

Answer (score 202, accepted):

The two concepts aren't related any more than any other type-related concepts.

In short, a `TypeVar` is a variable you can use in type signatures so you can refer to the same unspecified type more than once, while a `NewType` is used to tell the type checker that some values should be treated as their own type.

## [Type Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)

To simplify, type variables let you refer to the same type more than once without specifying exactly which type it is.

In a definition, a single type variable always takes the same value.

```
# (This code will type check, but it won't run.)
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List, Tuple

# Two type variables, named T and R
T = TypeVar('T')
R = TypeVar('R')

# Put in a list of Ts and get out one T
def get_one(x: List[T]) -> T: ...

# Put in a T and an R, get back an R and a T
def swap(x: T, y: R) -> Tuple[R, T]:
    return y, x

# A simple generic class that holds a value of type T
class ValueHolder(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T):
        self.value = value
    def get(self) -> T:
        return self.value

x: ValueHolder[int] = ValueHolder(123)
y: ValueHolder[str] = ValueHolder('abc')
```

Without type variables, there wouldn't be a good way to declare the type of `get_one` or `ValueHolder.get`.

There are a few other options on `TypeVar`. You can restrict the possible values by passing in more types (e.g. `TypeVar(name, int, str)`), or you can give an upper bound so every value of the type variable must be a subtype of that type (e.g. `TypeVar(name, bound=int)`).

Additionally, you can decide whether a type variable is covariant, contravariant, or neither when you declare it. This essentially decides when subclasses or superclasses can be used in place of a generic type. [PEP 484 describes these concepts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) in more detail, and refers to additional resources.

## [NewType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype)

A `NewType` is for when you want to declare a distinct type without actually doing the work of creating a new type or worry about the overhead of creating new class instances.

In the type checker, `NewType('Name', int)` creates a subclass of `int` named "Name."

At runtime, `NewType('Name', int)` is not a class at all; it is actually the identity function, so `x is NewType('Name', int)(x)` is always true.

```
from typing import NewType

UserId = NewType('UserId', int)

def get_user(x: UserId): ...

get_user(UserId(123456)) # this is fine
get_user(123456) # that's an int, not a UserId

UserId(123456) + 123456 # fine, because UserId is a subclass of int
```

To the type checker, `UserId` looks something like this:

```
class UserId(int): pass
```

But at runtime, `UserId` is basically just this:

```
def UserId(x): return x
```

There's almost nothing more than that to a `NewType` at runtime. As of Python 3.8.1, its [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/typing.py#L1787-L1811) is almost exactly as follows:

```
def NewType(name, type_):
    def identity(x):
        return x
    identity.__name__ = name
    return identity
```

Comment: What would the benefits be of `MyInt = NewType('MyInt', int)` over the simpler `MyInt = int`?

Comment: @physicalattraction in the second option the type of the MyInt still will be int, so you're creating a type alias implicitly. In the first option, you're creating a new type. i.e. if your function return MyInt (from option 1), then type checker won't allow you to return int

Comment: @physicalattraction the benefit becomes apparent when the following is true:  All `MyInt` are `int`, but not all `int` are `MyInt`.   Perhaps a better example would be `ZipCode`.