# Why does the NewType function not check for the correct variable type?

Tags: python

I am practicing clean code and annotations in my python code. I do not get what is the functionality of defining `NewType` objects if their type is not being checked.

Example:

```
UserId = NewType('UserId', int)
some_id = UserId('Hello World!')
type(some_id)

>> str
```

I would expect some kind of warning or error indicating types do not match... or maybe:

```
UserId = NewType('UserId', int)
some_id = UserId('Hello World!')
type(some_id)

>> UserId
```

but it does not.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UserId` you created with NewType only works for type annotations. Type annotations are only for static analysis (at least up till now), so IDEs like pycharm and tools like mypy use it to implement auto complete or error checking, etc.

If you want a "real" UserId type (a type at runtime), you can subclass int by yourself.

```py
class UserId(int):
    pass

print(UserId(3))
# By the way, UserId('Hello world!') will raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is a dynamically typed language. Variable types don't have to be declared before assigning a value to a variable in Python. Annotations and type hints are used by some IDEs to warn about type mismatches.
To actually check the variable type in a function you can use `isinstance`:

```
def NewType(UserId: int)
    if not isinstance(UserId, int):
        raise TypeError("userid must be an integer")
    # your function code here
    return result
```

You can check multiple types simultaneously grouping them as a tuple:

```
isinstance(variable, (int, float))
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I think it could also be made with `assert` statement. Either way, thanks a lot Carlos!

Comment: That is correct. The only difference is the behavior when using `assert`: it will exit the code execution raising an AssertionError, and that may not be what you want.

Comment: Please check the answer by "jirassimok" at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755948/what-is-the-difference-between-typevar-and-newtype  - I changed the inner function to check for proper type.

Answer (score 0):

```
def NewType(name, type_):
    def identity(x):
        if(isinstance(x, type_)):
            return x
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Input value is not of type {type_}")
    identity.__name__ = name
    return identity
>>> UserId = NewType("UserId", int)
>>> a = UserId("123")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in identity
ValueError: Input value is not of type <class 'int'>
>>> a = UserId(123)
>>> a
123
```