# TypeVar confusion, how to type callback functions?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

```
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar, Any

ParamArray = TypeVar("ParamArray", Tuple[Any, ...])
```

The concept is; a ParamArray is just a tuple of values. I have a function

```
def integrate(func, a, b, args=()):
    delta = 0.1
    running_total = 0.
    for x in range(a, b, step=delta):
        running_total += func(x, args) * delta
    return running_total
```

As such I was trying to type it:

```
def integrate(func:Callable[[float, ParamArray], float], a: float, b: float, args: ParamArray=()) -> float:
```

to try and convey the fact that the args ParamArray is the same thing that gets passed to func so the callback must be able to accept whatever args are passed.

I'm getting a few errors

> ```
> TypeVar cannot have only a single constraint
> Argument 2 to "TypeVar" has incompatible type "object"; expected "Type[Any]"
> Variable "typealiases.ParamArray" is not valid as a type
> ```

Comment: Have you tried to do your task with function:
collections.namedtuple()?

Answer (score 1):

First off, As `a` and `b` are going to be used in the `range` object, they should be `int` not float. Also `step=` should be `int` too,so `delta` have to be `int` as well.

See this post : [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755948/what-is-the-difference-between-typevar-and-newtype)

> a TypeVar is a variable you can use in type signatures so you can
> refer to the same unspecified type more than once, while a NewType is
> used to tell the type checker that some values should be treated as
> their own type.

The error you are getting is because you can't have one constraint in TypeVar, in your case a single `Tuple`.

Actually you want that your `func`'s arguments to be an instance of `Tuple` of something(or a subclass of `Tuple`) and then the `args` argument be the exact same tuple. This can be done using `bound=` argument in `TypeVar`.

```
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar, Any, Callable

ParamArray = TypeVar("ParamArray", bound=Tuple[Any, Any])


def integrate(func: Callable[[ParamArray], float], a: int, b: int,
              args: ParamArray = ()) -> float:
    delta = 1
    running_total = 0.
    for x in range(a, b, step=delta):
        running_total += func(x, args) * delta
    return running_total


def fn1(t: Tuple[int, int]) -> float:
    pass

def fn2(t: Tuple[float, float]) -> float:
    pass

integrate(fn1, 10, 20, (1, 2))      #valid
integrate(fn2, 10, 20, (1.1, 2.2))  #valid
integrate(fn1, 10, 20, (1.1, 2.2))  #invalid
```

Now in the third case, you can see because `fn1` takes tuple of integers and we passed tuple of floats to the `args` parameter, it complains. (I know you will test the reversed situation with `fn2` passing tuple of integers and he doesn't complain. That's because an integer is also a float in type hints).